# How replace labels for ngx-charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-charts

How replace labels for ngx-charts?

Horizontal diagram consists of three lines. Each line has a label on the right side ('8000', '7500', '7300'). I need replace these labels to '100%', '90%', '3%'.

But labels on X axis should remain unchanged.

[image: Result].

My component code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  sources = [
    { "id": 0, "name": "qw", "value": 8000 },
    { "id": 1, "name": "er", "value": 7500 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "ty", "value": 7300 }
  ]

  percents = {
    0: '100%',
    1: '90%',
    2: '3%'
  }

  view: any[] = [400, 200];
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  showXAxisLabel = false;
  showYAxisLabel = false;
  showDataLabel = true;

  constructor() {}

}
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyq4j3)

I use ngx-charts 9.0 version.